# Regex, jQuery, Replace, Function, String Manipulation, Templating

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have the following function:

```js
function parseEntry(query, html, url) {

  // logic draft :(

  var re = new RegExp('{{{(.*)}}}');
  regex = query.replace(re, "$1");

  var newre = new RegExp(regex);
  regged = html.replace(newre, "$1");

  ret = query.replace(regex, regged);

  // parse selectors
  var re = new RegExp('{{(.*)}}');
  newtext = html.replace(re, "$1");

  ret = ret.replace(newtext, $(newtext).clone().html());

  // parse %url%
  ret = ret.replace("%url%", url);

  // ret remaining
  return ret;

}

// Called this way:
let output = parseEntry('static value %url% {{.thisclass}} {{{(\d+)}}}', '<h1 class="thisclass">Test</h1><h2 class="thisclass">Test2</h2> 1234 12', "http://perdu.com");

console.log(output)

/**
should return:
static value http://perdu.com TestTest2 123412
{{{triple brackets = regex}}}
{{double brackets = jquery}}
**/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Can you help refactoring parseEntry() function to return expected output?

All help appreciated!

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Can you help refactoring parseEntry() function to return expected output?

Comment: What does it return, if not the _"expected output"_? Do you have any errors?

Comment: Not sure why, but the regex '\d+' gets the slash removed, a bit confused on the regex stack...

Comment: (Thanks for adding snippet, didn`t even know you could do this on StackOverflow o_O)

Comment: @LucLaverdure - I think I can help but I'm not totally clear on what `parseEntry` is _supposed_ to do... it appears that it expects to receive... a custom template string, a URL and some HTML, and returns the custom template string, with the url inserted and text from entities with the same class as what is matched between `{{}}` appended?  Am I characterizing this correctly?

Comment: text between double brackets {{ }} should be a jquery selector, within triple brackets {{{ }}} a regex expression, and %url% replaced by the url parameter

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Ended up doing it myself, for the curious:

```js
function parseEntry(query, url, ht) {
 
 // parse regex expressions (triple brackets)
 var re = new RegExp('{{{(.*)}}}', 'g');
 q = query.match(re);
 for (qq in q) {
  var newregex = q[qq].replace("{{{", '').replace("}}}", '');
  newregex = new RegExp(newregex, 'g');
  newq = ht.match(newregex).join("");
  query = query.replace(q[qq], newq);
 }
 

 // parse jquery expressions (double brackets)
 re = new RegExp('{{(.*)}}', 'g');
 q = query.match(re);
 for (qq in q) {
  var newjq = q[qq].replace("{{", '').replace("}}", '');
  code = $('<div>'+ht+'</div>').find(newjq);
  appendHTML = '';
  code.each(function() {
   appendHTML += $(this).html();
  })
  
  query = query.replace(q[qq], appendHTML);
  
 }
 

 // parse %url%
 ret = query.replace("%url%", url);
 
 // ret remaining
 return ret;
}

let output = parseEntry('static value %url% {{.thisclass}} {{{(\\d+)}}}', "http://perdu.com", '<h1 class="thisclass">Test</h1><h2 class="thisclass">Test2</h2> 1234 12');

console.log(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I undersand, but this is an attempt using different approaches I think are useful in this kind of situations. There are examples of `split()`, `replace()` and the `createElement` hack to parse html.

```
var query = 'static value %url% {{.thisclass}} {{{(\d+)}}}';
var html = '<h1 class="thisclass">Test</h1><h2 class="thisclass">Test2</h2> 1234 12';
var url =  "http://perdu.com";

query = query.split(" ").map(o=>{
        return o.replace(/\{\{\{(.*)\}\}\}/g, "$1");
}).map(o=>{
        return o.replace(/\{\{(.*)\}\}/g, "$1");
});

var el = document.createElement( 'div' );
el.innerHTML = "<div class='outer'>"+html+"</div>";

var t1 = $("h1").text(); 
var t2 = $("h2").text();
var out = $(".outer").text();

var newArr = [];
newArr.push(query[0]+" "+query[1]+" "+url+" "+t1+t2+out);
newArr.push("{{{triple brackets = "+query[4]+"}}}");
newArr.push("{{double brackets = "+query[3]+"}}");

console.log(newArr);
newArr.map(o=>{
$("#res").append(o+"<br>");
});
```

Full example here: http://jsfiddle.net/k8em5twd/6/

Answer (score 0):

So if this question is as simple as "why didn't the backslash show up in my output", then the answer is also very simple. Try escaping the backslash in your input string like so:

```
let output = parseEntry('static value %url% {{.thisclass}} {{{(\\d+)}}}', '<h1 class="thisclass">Test</h1><h2 class="thisclass">Test2</h2> 1234 12', "http://perdu.com");
```

The key is that `{{{(\d+)}}}` becomes `{{{(\\d+)}}}`. This way the slash is recognized as a character. Otherwise, `\d` is treated as an escape sequence. Output below.

```js
function parseEntry(query, html, url) {

  // logic draft :(

  var re = new RegExp('{{{(.*)}}}');
  regex = query.replace(re, "$1");

  var newre = new RegExp(regex);
  regged = html.replace(newre, "$1");

  ret = query.replace(regex, regged);

  // parse selectors
  var re = new RegExp('{{(.*)}}');
  newtext = html.replace(re, "$1");

  ret = ret.replace(newtext, $(newtext).clone().html());

  // parse %url%
  ret = ret.replace("%url%", url);

  // ret remaining
  return ret;

}

// Called this way:
// THIS LINE IS CHANGED:
let output = parseEntry('static value %url% {{.thisclass}} {{{(\\d+)}}}', '<h1 class="thisclass">Test</h1><h2 class="thisclass">Test2</h2> 1234 12', "http://perdu.com");

console.log(output)

/**
should return:
static value http://perdu.com TestTest2 123412
{{{triple brackets = regex}}}
{{double brackets = jquery}}
**/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```